# Save integer in if and else statement Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get a percentage for a number and use it twice in a statement. So basically what my code does is check whether attendance is "present" or "late" and if true then add 1 to count and add 1 to count2. Otherwise if attendance is "Absent" add 1 more to count2 and at display count(present) / count2(total). 
Here is a snippet of my code:

```
func retrieveImnpd(){


    let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    let intakeRef = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(userId!).child("Intake")

    intakeRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let intake = snapshot.value{

            var count = 0
            var count2 = 0
            var perc = 0

            self.ref.child("Attendance").child("Checkin").child("BM050-3-3-IMNPD").child(intake as! String).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

                if let nodeData = snapshot.value, !(nodeData is NSNull) {
                    let nodeData = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, Any>
                    for(_, value) in nodeData {
                        if let dict = value as? NSDictionary {
                            if let attendance = dict.object(forKey: "Attendance") as? String{

                                if attendance == "Present" || attendance == "Late"{
                                    count+=1
                                }
                                count2+=1

                                //self.imnpdLabel.text = String(count) + "/" + String(count2) + " (" + String(perc) + "%)"
                                perc = count/count2 * 100
                                if perc >= 80{
                                    self.imnpdLabel.textColor = UIColor.green
                                }
                                else{
                                    self.imnpdLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
                                }
                                self.imnpdLabel.text = String(count) + "/" + String(count2) + " (" + String(perc) + "%)"

                                //print(attendance)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    print("No Data...")
                }
            })

        }
    }) { (Error) in
        print("unable to retrieve name from nameRef")
    }

}
```

I'm retrieving the attendance from Firebase and it is working as expected when there is "present" attendance but I can't manage to change the percentage when there is an "Absent". I tried calculating the percentage again after adding 1 in the else statement but it returns 0 and I don't know how to get 50% if the attendance is 1/2. 
I'm still new to swift so any help will really be appreciated!

Output I'm getting when adding print statements:

```
1
1
1
2
```

I guess that's because it got 1 attendance as "present" and 1 as "absent" so it shows the count and count2 for both events

Comment: Not related to your question but you should take a look at Swift enumerations and how to use a `switch` statement to make the conditional code more readable

Comment: Your loops seem a bit out of shape. You should collect all your counts first then outside of your loops you should be calculating percentages and setting your labels. In other words, your `var count` and `var count2` should be on the same level as your `var perc = ...` and `imnpdLabel.text = ...`

Comment: Also your vars and where you set your labels should be inside `intakeRef.observeSingleEvent`

Comment: Finally your `count2` (which I would call `totalCount` to make it easier to follow) can be done once outside the `if attendance == "Present" || attendance == "Late"`. remove it from the `if` and put it outside and get rid of your `else`. In other words, it doesn't matter what the value of attendance is, it will always be incremented.

Comment: What do you mean it should be on the same level as ```imnpdLabel.text = ...``` because that is inside the if statement

Comment: @Kubee I updated my code but still getting 0% as a result

Comment: @QuintonLance123 I suspect it could be the `type` that you are using. Both `count` and `count2` are `Int`, and 1/2 will return 0. Try using `doubles` instead, ie `1.0/2.0`.

Comment: @QuintonLance123 I mean the same indent level.  Meaning the same scope (the same parent parenthesis (`{}`)). In your code you are setting your label and recomputing your percent on every `for` iteration. I think you need to take a step back and learn about `for` loops and `if` statements, you're jumping way too far ahead.  Also, I didn't notice this at first, but you have an observer inside another observer. Maybe thats how firebase works. I don't use it myself.  But I really doubt it.

Comment: @Kubee changing it to float fixed the issue!! Thanks a lot! I think yes that's how firebase works because when i retrieve a data from firebase i can't save it anywhere to use it again after so i have to put one in another

Comment: I want to display the count as Int but the perc as float. How can i do that? Because when i just change perc to float its still 0.0 and when i change all to float the counts shows decimal